# Removing a constraint from node using Cypher

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb

I know that the following code says that every node with the label `City` has a unique value for the `location` property.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:City)
ASSERT c.location IS UNIQUE;
```

So this code forbids me to have two cities with the same name in one country, e.g. there can be only one London in England. Now I need to turn the constraint off. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to "switch off" a constraint. You have to drop it using the [DROP CONSTRAINT](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/syntax/#administration-constraints-syntax-drop) command. This will delete the constraint.

Make sure you have the constraint name before dropping it. If you are not sure about the constraint name, then you can list all constraints using the [SHOW CONSTRAINTS](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/examples/#administration-constraints-list-constraint) command. It is always a good practice to specify a constraint name when creating it. In the below example, I specified the constraint name as `constraint_city`:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT constraint_city ON (c:City)
ASSERT c.location IS UNIQUE;
```

Then, to drop the constraint:

```
DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_city;
```